# How can I stick button to a mat-drawer?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat drawer to the right of the screen and I am trying to stick a button to it, so the overall design is clear.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eacm5.png)

How can I manage to do this action? So far I have tried adding the button inside of the drawer and giving it a negative left: -10px in order to overlay the drawer.

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" [hasBackdrop]="false">
      <mat-drawer style="width: 600px;" position="end" #drawer2 [mode]="over">
        <button style="left:  -10px; z-index: 1000;" mat-raised-button (click)="drawer2.toggle()">Side Nav</button> HERE
        <mat-tab-group>
          <mat-tab>
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
              <mat-icon> layers</mat-icon>
              <span>Componenti</span>
            </ng-template>
            <components [itemCategoryAreas]="itemCategoryAreas"></components>
          </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab>
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
              <mat-icon>wallpaper</mat-icon>
              <span>Disegno</span>
            </ng-template>
            Content 1
          </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab>
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
              <mat-icon>list</mat-icon>
              <span>Checklist</span>
            </ng-template>
            Content 1
          </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
      </mat-drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might help! Try something like this:

```
.app-toolbar {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* For macOS/iOS Safari */
    top: 0; /* Sets the sticky toolbar to be on top */
    z-index: 1000; /*app's content doesn't overlap the toolbar */
}
```

don't forget to change the classname though, Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I am trying to do is different. I am basically trying to stick a button that is always visible on the screen to the edge of a mat-drawer. Like the top of a physical folder, that has a title.

Answer (score 0):

Then,

If you want your button to stick permanent to its position, you should use

```
position: fixed;
```

instead of

```
position: sticky;
```